# Dynamically add and remove post title

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my wordpress website i create an Ajax search and search `post_title`. The code is here...

**Function and script:**

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'ajax_fetch' );
function ajax_fetch() {
?>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function fetch(){
  jQuery.ajax({
      url: ajaxwpse.ajaxurl,
      type: 'post',
      data: { action: 'data_fetch', keyword: jQuery('#keyword').val() },
      success: function(data) {
          jQuery('#datafetch').html( data );
    }
  });
 }
</script>
<?php
 }
add_action('wp_ajax_data_fetch' , 'data_fetch');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_data_fetch','data_fetch');
  function data_fetch(){

    if (  esc_attr( $_POST['keyword'] ) == null ) { die(); }
     $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 's' => esc_attr( $_POST['keyword'] ), 'post_type' => array('mobile','tablet') ) );
    if( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    while( $the_query->have_posts() ): $the_query->the_post(); ?>

    <div>
    <button class="post-link" rel="<?php the_ID(); ?>"> ADD </button>
    <li><a href="#" id="<?php the_ID(); ?>"><?php the_title();?></a></li> 
    </div>

    <?php endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();  
    endif;
    die();
}
```

After sucessfully search with Ajax Now i need to add `post_title` from search to div `id="post-container"` dynamically.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="keyword" id="keyword" onkeyup="fetch()" placeholder="Search to add"></input>

<div id="datafetch"></div>  // successfuly ajax Search Result Here

<div id="post-container"> </div>  // Trying to add post title here
```

I create a `ADD` button in search result to add post_title into div.

**How dynamically add post_title from search field to div with button?**

Comment: Instead of replacing just the contents of `#datafetch`, why not add the `#post-container` div to the generated HTML and insert both into a parent div?

Comment: @ChrisG please post answer about the idea its good. Explain with answer how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to attach click event to your button the get the `post_title` and `append` it to the div :

```
$(function(){
    $('body').on('click', '.post-link', function(){
        var post_title = $(this).closest('div').find('a').text();
        $('#post-container').append( post_title );
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$(function(){
  $('body').on('click', '.post-link', function(){
    var post_title = $(this).closest('div').find('a').text();

    if( $('#post-container p').length < 4 )
    $('#post-container').append( '<p>' + post_title + ' ------ <a href="#" class="remove-title">REMOVE</a></p>' );
    else
      alert('You could add max 4 titles');
  });

  $('body').on('click', '.remove-title', function(){
    $(this).closest('p').remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <button class="post-link"> ADD </button>
  <li>
    <a href="#">The title 1 HERE</a>
  </li> 
</div>

<div>
  <button class="post-link"> ADD </button>
  <li>
    <a href="#">The title 2 HERE</a>
  </li> 
</div>

<div>
  <button class="post-link"> ADD </button>
  <li>
    <a href="#">The title 3 HERE</a>
  </li> 
</div>

<hr>
<div id="post-container"> </div>
```

Comment: How can i limit it to add max 4 post_title. and if i add wrong title how to remove it from div #post-container.

Comment: The `post_title` is just a string ?

Comment: Check please the snippet in my update, i hope it will give you an idea.

Comment: Thanks its working. and something about maximum add title 4

Answer (score 1):

Compose both divs in your PHP function, then put them in a single `<div>`, like this:

**PHP:**

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_data_fetch','data_fetch');
function data_fetch(){

  if (  esc_attr( $_POST['keyword'] ) == null ) { die(); }
  $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 's' => esc_attr( $_POST['keyword'] ), 'post_type' => array('mobile','tablet') ) );
  if( $the_query->have_posts() ) :

  // compose $post_title 
  $post_title = "...";

  echo "<div id=\"datafetch\">";
  while( $the_query->have_posts() ): $the_query->the_post(); ?>

    <div>
    <button class="post-link" rel="<?php the_ID(); ?>"> ADD </button>
  <li><a href="#" id="<?php the_ID(); ?>"><?php the_title();?></a></li> 
    </div>

  <?php endwhile;
  echo "</div><div id=\"post-container\">" . $post_title . "</div>";
  wp_reset_postdata();  
  endif;
  die();
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" name="keyword" id="keyword" onkeyup="fetch()" placeholder="Search to add"></input>

<div id="result"></div>
```

**JS:**

```
// in your ajax call
success: function(data) {
  jQuery('#result').html( data );
}
```